# How prove $\frac{2}{3}<\frac{3x^6+15x^2+2}{2x^6+15x^4+3}\le\frac{3}{2}$

Tags: calculus, inequality

> Let $x\in(0,1]$, show that
>   $$\dfrac{2}{3}<\dfrac{3x^6+15x^2+2}{2x^6+15x^4+3}\le\dfrac{3}{2}$$

My try: since
$$\begin{align}\dfrac{3x^6+15x^2+2}{2x^6+15x^4+3} &=\dfrac{\dfrac{3}{2}(2x^6+15x^4+3)+15x^2-\dfrac{45}{2}x^4-\dfrac{5}{2}}{2x^6+15x^4+3} \\ &=\dfrac{3}{2}-\dfrac{5}{2}\cdot\dfrac{9x^4-6x^2+1}{2x^6+15x^4+3}\end{align}$$
then
I can't,Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hey, just derive.

Comment: maybe this inequality have nice methods,Thank you

Comment: As Ivan suggested, just derive. The derivative is quite simple (it simplfies a lot. Try it and you will probably better understand the meaning of the inequalities.

Comment: are you familiar with the standard technics to solve such an inequation?

Answer (score 7):

It is enough to note that for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$
$$
\dfrac{3}{2}-\dfrac{3x^6+15x^2+2}{2x^6+15x^4+3}=\dfrac{5}{2}\cdot\dfrac{(3x^2-1)^2}{2x^6+15x^4+3}\geq 0
$$
and 
$$
\dfrac{3x^6+15x^2+2}{2x^6+15x^4+3}-\dfrac{2}{3}=\dfrac{5x^2(x^2-3)^2}{3(2x^6+15x^4+3)}\geq 0
$$

Comment: Did you just guess that this would work out, and computed it all?  I would have guessed that if I attempted this method of proof the results wouldn't factor in a nice way and would have sooner tried finding local maxima and minima, etc.  Just wondering how is there was some kind of trick to knowing ahead of computation that this would factor, or if you just decided to try it and it all worked out fortuitously.

Comment: This super-duper technique is called trial and error

Comment: Ah, so, without the snark:  You didn't know it'd work out before you started calculating.  Thanks.